# Retreive max/min possible values for an Integer column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to get the maximum and minimum **possible** values on an Integer type column in SQLAlchemy?  Essentially I'd like to test a value before inserting it into the database.

**EDIT:**

Apparently people are thinking I'm asking for min/max values stored in the database.  I'm talking about `MAXINT` kind of information on the column types.

Right now the only way I can see is to extract what datatype is generated in the DDL and then having a table of all of those with maximum/minimum possible values.  So, for example, know that `Integer()` maps to a signed 32-bit integer value.  I was hoping there was something already in-built to determine that information (say, for types that were user generated).

Comment: added more information...  I'm not looking for existing values in a database, but what possible values can be inserted without throwing an exception.